# Modifying a Regular Expression to be case insentsitve

Tags: regex

I have the following reg exp...

```
[0-9]{6}\\-[A-Z]{4}_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}_[a-zA-Z]{3}_(Web_)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
```

It looks for a long file name with the word "Web" in it? However it is case-sensitive, meaning it catches the first of these Strings but not the second...

```
198284-QPYW_20130724_144810_ABC_Web_XNHVAS.mov
198284-QPYW_20130724_144810_ABC_web_XNHVAS.mov
```

Can anyone show me how I can tweak so it catches both of these?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation for flags in whatever regex engine you're using.

Comment: What language are you developing on?

Comment: Depending on the regex engine you are using, you can just use a flag to make it case-insensitive. Otherwise in your regex, change the `(Web_)?` part to:  `([Ww]eb_)?` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the regex engine you are using, you can just use a flag to make it case-insensitive. In most cases it's the `i` flag.

Otherwise in your regex, change the `(Web_)?` part to: `([Ww]eb_)?`

So your full regex would be this:

```
\\-[A-Z]{4}_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}_[a-zA-Z]{3}_([Ww]eb_)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
```